# Solving Euler #14 with bruteforce in Python

Tags: python, brute-force

I tried to bruteforce [euler problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=14) with python without much success.

I used the itertools module but it was too slow. Then I found the formula to solve the problem.

Is there a way to solve the problem using bruteforce?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the problem, the formula you used to solve (preferably with your current code) so that others can optimize it. Also if you found the formula, any specific reason to use brute force

Comment: Brute-force methods tend to be slow.

Comment: Define "brute force." Without a formula, you can still [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). I suppose that might still be "brute force" -- just a litte less "brute."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the intermediate value in a dictionary and do a kind of a dynamic programming.

```
numbers = {1:0}
max = -1
startMax = -1
for i in range(2, 1000 000):
    n = i
    steps = 0
    while n>=i:
        if n&2 == 0:
            n = n/2
        else:
            n = 3*n + 1
        steps = steps + 1
    # n < i, hence it must already be stored in the dictionary
    steps = steps + numbers[n]
    if steps > max:
        max = steps
        startMax = i
    numbers[i] = steps
    return startMax
```

Another approach may be to store every number you encounter and always check whether the number you are currently on is in the map. But I guess this may take a bit longer with so many dictionary look-ups:

```
numbers = {1:0}
max = -1
for i in range(2, 1000 000):
    if i in numbers:
        steps = numbers[i]
    else:
        n = i
        steps = 0
        found = False

        while not found:
            if n&2 == 0:
                n = n/2
            else:
                n = 3*n + 1
            if n in numbers:
                steps = numbers[n]
                found = True
            else:
                newNumbers.append(n)
        # Store all the new numbers into the dictionary
        for num in newNumbers:
            steps = steps + 1
            numbers[num] = steps
    if steps>max:
        max = steps
        startMax = i
return startMax
```

You may want to do some testing to find out which one is better, but my bet would be on the first one.

Answer (score -1):

[pypy](http://pypy.org/) is "python with the optimizations turned on".

Get it here:
   http://pypy.org/download.html#default-with-a-jit-compiler

To use it, just write `pypy` where you'd normally write `python`. It's quite compatible. The chief difference is that C-based extensions written for python won't work in pypy, although many people are working hard to fix that.

---

I feel compelled to defend my answer. Given this very simple brute-force solution:

```
"Solve Project-Eueler #14"
from collections import namedtuple
Chain = namedtuple('Chain', 'length, start')


def calculate_chain(i):
    start = i
    length = 1
    while i != 1:
        length += 1
        if i & 1: # `i` is odd
            i = 3 * i + 1
        else:
            # Divide by two, efficiently.
            i = i >> 1
    return Chain(length, start)

def find_largest_chain(maxint):
    largest_chain = Chain(0, 0)
    for i in xrange(1, maxint+1):
        chain = calculate_chain(i)
        if chain > largest_chain:
            largest_chain = chain
    return largest_chain


def commandline_interface():
    from sys import argv
    maxint = int(argv[1])
    print find_largest_chain(maxint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commandline_interface()
```

The runtime in python is 23 seconds:

```
$ /usr/bin/time python 10177836.py 999999
Chain(length=525, start=837799)
22.94user 0.04system 0:23.09elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15648maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1109minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

and in pypy it's .93 seconds:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ~/packages/pypy-1.8/bin/pypy 10177836.py 999999
Chain(length=525, start=837799)
0.66user 0.10system 0:00.93elapsed 81%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 63152maxresident)k
48inputs+0outputs (1major+4194minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Simply using pypy yields a 2373% speed improvement, with a particular algorithm. I see no reason why the OP would not see a similar improvement with his own code.

Comment: Please leave a comment for downvotes...

Comment: It's far far away from the question. OP was asking about a specific project euler problem, not how to run python fast. And no optimizing compiler can convert a bad algorithm to a good algorithm. The question is about algorithm.

Comment: @taskinoor: In fact it's a direct solution to the problem. He wants to run a *particular* algorithm more quickly, and this is a very easy and very good way. For python performance, pypy is *the* answer. I agree that pypy will not fix algorithmic problems, but given that he particularly wants to use a "brute force" approach, this is not algorithms question.

Comment: Using right-shift rather than division yields a 6% speedup in python and a 59% speedup in pypy, widening the performance gap to nearly 30x.